# on which port my asterisk software is running

Tags: port, asterisk

Is there a way to find out on which port my asterisk software is running using command line interface or by any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the sip.conf file, located at `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf` it will tell you which port it will run.

For example:

```
[general]
port = 5060
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
context = error
qualify=no
srvlookup=yes
```

Answer (score 7):

Asterisk supports more Protocols than SIP and IAX2,
but these Ports are the typical Voice-Protocol Ports and may get forwarded from your Router (Firewall) to the Asterisk Server (because of **NAT**):

- UDP:5060 SIP (sip.conf), newer Versions support TCP:5060
- UDP:10000-20000 RTP (rtp.conf) for the media stream, a higher Portrange
- UDP:5036 IAX2

You can also check the asterisk (modules) ports with:

`lsof -n -i -P`

You may find additional ports, based on your loaded modules (modules.conf) and configuration, for example TCP:5038 (manager.conf).

List your modules with:

`asterisk -rx 'module show'`

or for older versions:  `asterisk -rx 'show modules'` .

Modules can be autoloaded and disabled with `noload => modulename.so` in modules.conf.

Answer (score 3):

I always use netstat command as it is a good option to understand all the ports opened by Asterisk process
netstat -anp | grep asterisk